# Computer has been slowly starting to fail

Tags: windows, boot, hardware-failure

I have a computer that has been slowly starting to fail over the past several years. Now recently it often stops at the message "boot from CD" (it doesn't normally boot from CD, it just prints that message then goes on to the hard drive).

Several months ago Windows 8.1 stopped booting (it worked every now and then), at which point I switched to the Grub bootloader that I had installed before and used Linux. I can access the files on the Windows hard drive just fine from Linux and never have any problems. But the problem usually seemed to happen when I would start transferring a lot of files off of the computer across the network (to do a backup). All of a sudden it would just turn off without a BSOD, and wouldn't start for a while.

Linux is installed on one hard drive and Windows is installed on the other. Neither of the hard drives seemed to have any problems mounted on the Linux OS. Access speed seemed to be good, and it wasn't hard to access files. Not sure if I tried a bulk transfer on Linux or not.

One other thing is that the problems always seemed to be in the BIOS part of the boot process. Sometimes there would be garbled characters on the list of detected drives (not the boot menu, just the startup screen).

So now I have a basically dead computer, and I am wondering if the problem is memory, motherboard, or power supply or something else.

Comment: One thing to check is the clock battery, usually a coin-type Li cell. See https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/11/618460171318429760/

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.